# QML: MessageDialog closes on click outside

Tags: qt, qml, messagedialog

I'm trying to show an QML MessageDialog with Qt 6.4.3. This dialog should be closed with the provided button.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Dialogs

ApplicationWindow  {
    id: window

    width: 800
    height: 600

    visible: true

    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: dialog.open()

    MessageDialog{
        id: dialog

        modality: Qt.ApplicationModal

        title: "Test Dialog"
        text: "My Text"

        buttons: MessageDialog.Ok
    }
}
```

PROBLEM: The dialog is dismissed, if the user clickes outside the dialog. I would expect the dialog to stay visible until the user pressed the OK button.

What is my mistake in the following example? How can I achieve, that the dialog stays visible until the user pressed the button?

Comment: That should be the effect of *modality*. Have you tried `modality: Qt.WindowModal`?

Comment: Yes, this has the same effect. Clicking outside the MessageDialog closes it.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49801910/19374684 Apparently modality only means that a dialog prevents the rest of the windows from receiveing the events, but not necessarily that the dialog itself does not close. If you want to achieve that on desktop you have to set `closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape`

Comment: Qt6 MessageDialog has no closePolicy

Comment: I consider this a QML bug and reported it: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-112328

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in a workaround, you can force the dialog to stay up until the user accepts by catching the reject and forcing the dialog to open again:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Dialogs
Page {
    MessageDialog{
        id: dialog
        modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
        title: "Test Dialog"
        text: "My Text"
        buttons: MessageDialog.Ok
        onRejected: Qt.callLater(dialog.open)
    }
    Button {
        text: qsTr("Open")
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        y: parent.height * 2 / 10
        onClicked: dialog.open()
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAByHicZVDBTsMwDL33K6yeOg5lcOwNypFqDPUHQmp1plnSJZ5EmfbveKlI2fDBit97eX4y7UfnGba8PZIeMroay9pZ9s6EW/yFlHF9yN5Uj3DKQKrBEGSamRm6FHUVdBFL0N51yhBPldiVT+NoSCsmZ5sLnlRMbLCCvMXAMLvmC4lfLFwzQSuvBf84Mjsbqus05WZICmff8RM1YxfXa2XMq2L0xRyydCPaVVSfY3+OjnC6WX0IrS/yjYjzVaKU1TvnQymNvuVyytRoxbuCUXl5/SPSz2mRIPU7hjt4hHt4WP/JXcudBkznjEmL36jnH/SQipE=)

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. This is working for a dialog with just having a OK-Button. If you have a CANCEL-Button as well, this is not working, because you can't dismiss the dialog in this case.

Comment: @JürgenLutz for the OK-CANCEL scenario, you have several additional workarounds. Either transition to a YES-NO question. Or, you can consider implementing you can consider replacing the standard buttons with your own by writing `footer: RowLayout { Button ... }`. That way you can differentiate a cancel-button-click versus onRejected and handle each case appropriately.

Comment: Sure. But I will leave it like it is for now. Hopefully they will fix the bug I have reported (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-112328)